# not able to show $this->validation->error_string

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Hello this is my onload function :-

```
  $(function() {
            <?php if( isset ($this->validation->error_string) && $this->validation->error_string != '') {?>
                str = '<?php echo $this->validation->error_string;?>';
                alert(str);
            <?php }?>
        });
```

And i always get this error :-

```
unterminated string literal
    str = '<p>The Username field is required.</p>\n
```

Even though there are validation errors i always get this error in firebug. However when i just echo it out in body tag it works fine. How do i solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode new lines in your output so it'll be valid JavaScript, for example using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
$(function() {
  <?php if( isset ($this->validation->error_string) && $this->validation->error_string != '') {?>
  var str = '<?php echo json_encode($this->validation->error_string);?>';
  alert(str);
  <?php }?>
});
```

JavaScript strings can't span lines...you'll get an "unterminated string literal" error, exactly what you're seeing.  Also, use `var` as to not create global variables, or use no variable at all, like this:

```
$(function() {
  <?php if( isset ($this->validation->error_string) && $this->validation->error_string != '') {?>
  alert('<?php echo json_encode($this->validation->error_string);?>');
  <?php }?>
});
```

Another note, since you're alerting this, you'll probably want to remove the `<p></p>` wrapper, since that'll show up in the `alert()` as well.